# Driving a stepper motor to a set force

Tags: stepper-motor

I am trying to drive a Linear Actuator (stepper motor with a lead screw) to drive until a force of 15 pounds is reached then stop.  I am having trouble finding a good method to do this (I am new to stepper motors) can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am thinking of getting the motor with an encoder and adjusting a voltage/current until it will stall at 15 pounds and detecting that it did not move using the encoder then stopping the motor, is this a good way to go about this?

Comment: http://www.st.com/web/catalog/sense_power/FM142/CL851/SC1794/SS1498/LN1723/PF248592

Comment: I think you can also use back emf to detect a stall in the stepper. http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279185

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to put a encoder on the stepper motor, then you might as well not use a stepper motor.  The point of a stepper is to let you know accurate position open loop.  If you're going to close the loop, then you can get other motors that are cheaper, more efficient, and smaller at the same torque.

A brushless DC motor might be a good choice.  You inherently have position feedback, so you know where the motor is and can tell it stalled.  The current to generate the desired 15 pounds at the end of the mechanism will also be fairly predictable and consistant between units after having been measured once.

Comment: Wouldn't advancing motor age make the current-based heuristic inaccurate? It seems (to me) that having a sensor in the loop is unavoidable.

Comment: While a stepper doesn't seem right for this application, I would think that a combination of a stepper plus an encoder could be helpful in many circumstances which would require a motor to stop quickly and hold a position in the presence of externally-applied torque.  Most other kinds of motors would require the addition of a separate mechanical break to hold a position against significant torque without overheating.

Comment: @user: Motor age should have little to do with torque as a function of current, unless it has permanent magnets that loose their strength over time.  Outright measuring force or torque is better if you need it to be more accurate.  This is mostly a cost / accuracy / complexity tradeoff, which the OP gave little guidance on.

Comment: The reason for the stepper is because for this application we need a motor in each corner, and we need to make sure they move in sink.

Answer (score 4):

You could put a load cell on the nut if you want a really accurate force shutdown. You'll probably want to put some deliberate spring factor into the system so that each step represents a certain (rough) number of newtons force (or lbf in the Imperial system).

Comment: A closed-loop controller (instead of a simple shutdown - OP said "stop", not "shutdown") with the error input driven from a load cell would be the ideal solution imo.